# Will buildings disappear (and chunks change) if I go too far?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Somebody told me that if I travel too far from my house, it will disappear (possibly with my treasury). Is it true? Will the chunk change if I travel too far? I travelled across tens of thousands of blocks and the house was still there, but I don't know if it will change with being millions of blocks away. If it does, can I preserve the house with a map?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the chunk will not change, the person probably tricked you.

Answer (score 9):

No, Chunks will not get changed, only unload, which might have been what was meant. It basically means that say you had a furnace burning 16 iron ore. If you go far enough away the chunk will unload and the furnace will stop smelting until you load the chunk again, then it will continue. :)

Comment: I observed that with my crops. I got away for a long time,and when I returned,they were not completly grown. @Skye

Comment: It's basically because the more chunks you load the more RAM the game needs in order to run. That's why on modded servers Chunk/world/personal loaders are normally banned because of too many chunks being loaded and the lag involved.

Answer (score 5):

They were most likely joking or misinformed. Chunks that you've visited are saved in the world's region files. Even if you walk across the whole world, the things you've built won't disappear. Enjoy exploring!

Comment: But it will work if I load a world on the same seed as other (I mean if chunks remain the same on different world with the same seed)? @tuxedoandex

Comment: @John If you use the same seed to make a new world, the new world will be just as it was before you ever set foot in it. A new one won't have anything that you've in the old world.

Comment: This time I mean just about chunks. If I have a natural cave at X=12000 Y=42 and Z=8000 (just an example),will it remain in the newer world? @tuxedoandex

Comment: @John Yes, it'll be in any world with the same seed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only aware of one very specific situation in which chunks are altered after being generated.  Deep ocean biomes which have not been inhabited for more than three minutes [may have ocean monuments spawn in them](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocean_monument); the three-minute limit appears to exist specifically to *prevent* the "my house suddenly vanished" problem.  Other than this, the game does not modify existing chunks by itself.

Comment: Based on the link, in addition to the three minute rule the chunk must have been generated before the version of minecraft which added the monuments.

Comment: @Namfuak: It's not immediately clear to me that Minecraft [actually stores that information](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#NBT_structure).  It does have [per-chunk timestamps for saving](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Region_file_format#Chunk_Timestamps), but that's probably not good enough.

Comment: That page says that the chunk has a "V" tag, though the page claims it is that it is always set to 1.

Comment: @namfuak: They may be checking for whether the tag exists.  Older versions may not have had it.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes.*

If you travel far enough that your coordinates overflow, newly generated chunks will overwrite original ones. You do have to travel insanely far though, even further than where the farlands were.

Comment: You might want to get a bit more specific about what "insanely far" and "further than the farlands" means.

Comment: @Philipp now I can't find the exact numbers. The Wiki only mentions the limit from Beta 1.7 (X/Z ±34,359,738,368).

Comment: @Philipp far lands were removed in beta 1.8

Comment: I think he's talking about an overwrite caused by integer overflow, nothing to do with the far lands issue.

Comment: If it is an integer overflow issue, the limit would probably either be +2^31-1 | -2^31 or +2^63-1 | -2^63 depending on the size of the coordinate integer, so it would not be a practical problem for a person in survival (on top of the fact that you would have to travel 2^32 or 2^64 blocks total to overwrite a chunk you had already entered).

Comment: In 1.8, assuming no cheats, it is [not possible](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border) to go more than 3 * 10^8 meters ([Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)) from (0, 0).

Comment: @Kevin you can deactivate the border.

Comment: @Namfuak exactly. I heard that already, so this is probably what was told to OP. I can't find the original source along with exact figures though.

Comment: I play 1.8.7,so Far Lands are not existing. @Quentin

Comment: @John I'm only mentioning the Farlands as an idea of what kind of distance we're talking about. That is, the program-breaking kind.

Comment: I'm not sure there is technical foundation to this claim; if the coordinate did in fact overflow, then all math using it (involving looking up the chunk in the database) would be working on the overflowed value, hence the original chunk should be loadable, unless the map storage used some abnormal way of indexing chunks,

Comment: @Quentin: That's why I said "assuming no cheats."  If you want to cheat your way into breaking the game, that's your problem.

Comment: @hexafraction: It's entirely possible the game tracks block, chunk, and/or region coordinates separately to some extent.  It might at the very least become "confused" by excessively large coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

No not unless someone or something destroys it.